# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions does nothing at all

Tags: android, android-permissions

I made a class for requesting permissions called `PermissionsService`:

```
public void getPermission(final String androidManifestPermission, final int mPermissionCode, final String rational) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mactivity, androidManifestPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Snackbar.make(mLayout, rational, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mactivity, new String[]{androidManifestPermission}, mPermissionCode);
            }
        }).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mactivity, new String[]{androidManifestPermission}, mPermissionCode); <------ nothing happens when the flow reaches here
    }
}

public static enum PERMISSIONS {
    CAMERA_PERMISSION,
    GPS_PERMISSION
}
```

When flow reaches line `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mactivity, new String[]{androidManifestPermission}, mPermissionCode);` nothing happens at all.

The value of `mactivity` is `MainActivity`, the value of `androidManifestPermission` is `"android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"`.

I don't understand what the problem is.

**I noticed something quite interesting which may be related.**

The [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) function takes an activity as the first argument. But the call back `onRequestPermissionsResult`, which it executes, is defined in the interface ActivityCompat.[OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]))

How can that be? How can the function `requestPermissions` find the call back `onRequestPermissionsResult` in `Activity` (the first argument)?

Maybe that's related to my problem?

I tried making my Activity implement `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` ofcourse. When I annotated the function with `@Override` `onRequestPermissionsResult` the compiler complains that the function `onRequestPermissionsResult` (from the interface `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`) does not override a superclass.

My main concern is that I cannot get the OS to request the permission from the user.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**runOnUIThread**

I tried running `requestPermissions` on the UIThread like so (didn't work):

```
mactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mactivity, new String[]{androidManifestPermission}, mPermissionCode);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have permissions, the `requestPermissions` method will not show the permissions dialog.

If you don't have the permissions already, the dialog asking for permissions will be shown.

After the dialog is shown and the user allows or denies it. The callback method `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity will be called.

You cannot override the method `onRequestPermissionsResult` unless you are inside an activity.

However you can make a method in your helper class to delegate the permissions.

In your helper class:

```
public static void onRequestPermissionResult(/*params*/){
    //your code
}
```

And in your activity, override the method and pass it to your helper class:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionResult(/*params*/){
    PermissionsService.onRequestPermissionResult(/*params*/);
}
```

I have built a permissions library that can be used by anyone. You can have a look at the source code or directly use it by importing the library.

https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: Hi. I have tried to override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` inside the activity. It tells me that `method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: I know the problem that I have. Thanks ;)